# High Charts tooltip

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts, and I would like to remove the tooltip from the chart.

I did that by the following code:

```
tooltip: {
enabled: true,
}
```

My requirement is whatever displaying in the tooltip i want to show in top of the chart.
when we hover the mouse at any point that display area will update with the appropriate data as tooltip did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, the place and position of tool tip can not be changed. but, there is one by shifting the content of tooltip of somewhere else as given below.

'container' displays the chart and 'Info' block display the tool tip in example below.

```
<div id="info"></div>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Use formatter as given below:

```
chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
tooltip: {
        enabled: true,
        formatter: function() {
            $('#info').html('Value <b>'+ this.x +
                '</b> is <b>'+ this.y +'</b>');
            return false;
        }
      }
```

Comment: What about clearing the tooltip container data after mouse out?